# How do you display a 2d array of RGB values on a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java and I am wanting to make a basic 3D engine.
I want to take an array of colors and display it on the screen. Is there a simple and fast way to do this?

### EDIT

For example, if the array was

```
{{{255, 0, 0}, {255, 0, 0}}, {{255, 0, 0}, {255, 0, 0}}}
```

It would output a red square 2x2 pixels.

Comment: Yes. The third dimension is the rgb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a *proof of concept* (POC).

As described in [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) tutorial, you can perform custom painting by writing a class that extends `javax.swing.JPanel` and overriding its `paintComponent` method.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ColorArr extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    private int[][][] arr = {
                             {
                              {255, 0, 0},
                              {255, 0, 0}
                             },
                             {
                              {255, 0, 0},
                              {255, 0, 0}
                             }
                            };

    public ColorArr() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    @Override // javax.swing.JComponent
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++) {
                Color color = new Color(arr[row][col][0], arr[row][col][1], arr[row][col][2]);
                g.setColor(color);
                g.drawRect(row, col, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new ColorArr());
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture. A two-pixel by two-pixel, red square appears in the top, left corner.

[image: Screen capture of running Swing app.]

Comment: I have been playing around with this and I've noticed something weird: There are white dots all over the output. [Updated code](https://pastebin.com/QdSU3jG7)

Comment: @LeoMinton if you have a bug in your code, then post a new question that contains a [mcve]. Also describe your problem (which I assume is that you are not getting your desired results when running the code). And if your problem is that you are not getting desired results, then also write, in your question, what results you want to get.